# Michael Hartl guide chapter 5 rspec issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Once I completed Chapter 5 which titled "filling in the lay out"  and also the initial creation of the users, I ran rspec and I get the following:

```
1) PagesController GET 'home' should have the right title
 Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home")
   expected following output to contain a <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home</title> 

2) PagesController GET 'contact' should have the right title
 Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Contact")
   expected following output to contain a <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Contact</title> 

3) PagesController GET 'about' should have the right title
 Failure/Error: response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About")
   expected following output to contain a <title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About</title>
```

I have been working on this for a about a day now and I just do not know what I am doing wrong?  Also the pages launch perfectly fine as well

here is the pagescontroller code
    require 'spec_helper'

```
describe PagesController do
  render_views

  describe "GET 'home'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'home'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'home'
      response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Home")
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'contact'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'contact'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'contact'
      response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Contact")
    end
  end

  describe "GET 'about'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'about'
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get 'about'
      response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | About")
    end
  end
end
```

also here is my app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<title><%= @title %></title>
```

here is my layout_links_spec

```
require 'spec_helper'


it "should have a Home page at '/'" do
  get '/'
  response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Home")
end

it "should have a Contact page at '/contact'" do
  get '/contact'
  response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Contact")
end

it "should have have an About page at '/about" do
  get '/about'
  response.should have_selector('title', :content => "About")
end

it "should have a Help pageat '/help'" do
  get '/help'
  response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Help")
end

it "should have a signup page at '/signup'" do
  get '/signup'
  response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Sign up")
end

it "should have the right links on the layout" do
  visit root_path
  response.should have_selector('title', :content => "Home") 
end
end
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant code or particular section from Chapter 5 that is causing this issue.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you've included render_views

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe UsersController do
  render_views

  describe "GET 'new'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get :new
      response.should be_success
    end

    it "should have the right title" do
      get :new
      response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Sign up")
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It took me some time to figure out what the exact error was, but make sure you're following the instructions as they're laid out in the Mike's tutorial.

Mike's very efficient and thorough, but if you skip a step you'll get errors.  I saw the same issue and first you need to make sure you're using the most updated `static_pages_spec.rb` from listing **5.20**, the most updated routes file from listing **5.23** and make sure that you delete the `public\index.html` file.

Your errors should go away once you've completed those steps.